# Another site has the same logo as Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow

I noticed something rather odd and couldn't take my mind off it.
I visited this website [Martin Média](http://www.martinmedia.fr/) and I immediately recognised their logo as Stack Overflow's.

I checked like three times in order to be sure and I think it definitely is the same logo.
Now I'm not sure which one was created first but I know Stack Overflow was launched in 2008 and it reads 2010 on the other website.

My question is, isn't there some legal issue here?

Comment: The domain does exist since 2006 or earlier, but I can't find a clue since when the website is online. :/

Comment: @Bobby, seems to be late 2007 at the earliest: http://web.archive.org/web/*sa_/http://www.martinmedia.fr/

Comment: FWIW, I plugged the SO/SF/SU logos into TinEye and didn't find any knockoffs... including the one in question from Martin Média.

Comment: @Popular - did the image include the title?

Comment: @Chris: where possible, I used both with and without.  But the engine spit an "image not special enough to generate a unique signature"-type error for the SU no-title logo.

Comment: Double FWIW: I also plugged the knockoff logo into the engine and got no other knockoffs, but did get the real logo.

Comment: This is a great spot - ho wthe hell did you find it?

Comment: @Marko Actually I first saw it in the footer of a web agency's website [http://www.maecia.com/](http://www.maecia.com/) while browsing…

Comment: FYI, maecia.com still has the SO logo associated with martinmedia.fr as of today (2010-08-07).

Answer (score 18):

Wow, that's pretty egregious. We'll follow up on this one, because as it says in the footer:

> site design / logo © 2010 stack overflow internet services, inc;

Comment: Now the footer says "© 2010 Martin media group" (in French, according to Bing Translator). In any case, it's a blatant knock-off.

Comment: The company responsible (sjcom) is also citing it as an example, [here](http://www.sjcom.fr/category/realisation/) - or [direct image link](http://wp1.ecom54.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/MartinMedia-550x398.jpg)

Comment: @Marc ouch. This looks like the work of an intern with a grudge :)

Answer (score 10):

Message sent:

> RE: your stolen logo at http://www.martinmedia.fr
>
> The logo in your header at http://www.martinmedia.fr has been stolen from http://stackoverflow.com.  This logo has been in use for over 2 years at our site and was custom designed.
>
> Immediately cease using this logo and remove it from your pages here:
>   http://www.sjcom.fr/category/realisation/
>   and here:
>   http://wp1.ecom54.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/MartinMedia-550x398.jpg
>   and here:
>   http://www.martinmedia.fr/
>
> If I do not receive a reply from you within five days, we will make it clear that you have stolen our logo in every way possible.
>
> Michael Pryor
>   Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc.

## Update 1:

> Bonjour,
>   Je viens de recevoir votre e-mail au sujet du logo.
>
> Je vais examiner tout ça afin de comprendre le problème.
>
> Je vous contacte début de semaine prochaine.
>
> Sincères saluations,
>
> Steve Jaïch

Rough translation: I got your email about the logo, let me look into it, and I'll get back to you next week.

## Update 2:

Logo Removed 2010-08-17

Comment: Ugh. The thought of having to deal with this in the French legal system is clearly a waste of time.  Better to bring the power of internet shame down upon them.

Comment: I don't know, but according to their web site they gross 10 million euros per year: not too small. Also, according to Wikipedia, breaching copyright in France is a criminal offence known as 'counterfeiting', with possible fines and jail terms.

Comment: Looks like they've taken the image down

Comment: @Noel, http://wp1.ecom54.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/MartinMedia-550x398.jpg is still up

Comment: The second sentence translates to: "I will examine all this so that I can understand the problem." Wow, that's pretty arrogant!

Answer (score 2):

Just making people aware of this question in the conversation here: [What are the rules on using the Stack Overflow logo?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo)