# What is the relationship between the Pile Studios "Stack Overflow" app and Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, copyright, copyright-infringement

I was searching on the Google Play store (Japanese version) for a Stack Overflow client and I found *Stack Overflow* by Pile Studios.  The [website for the app](http://www.pilestudios.com/) claims

> Note: *We take no credit whatsoever for the website Stack Overflow itself*

But I'm confused about how they can make such a claim but use the *Stack Overflow* name and logo.

Is this application legitimate?  Can applications freely use the *Stack Overflow* name and logo?

Comment: Good find! That is pretty definitely an infringement of SE, Inc.'s copyright.

Comment: Part of your question is answered at [What are the rules on using the Stack Overflow logo?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo)

Comment: I think it's mainly a trademark violation. Using the logo is probably also a copyright violation, but that's only secondary.