# Can the different elements of the Stack Exchange pages be used in external sites?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, copyright

If I want to discuss certain elements of the Stack Exchange UI on external sites, is it alright to use images of those elements ?

Say, if I want to discuss the new Notifications UI, is it permissible to use screenshots in my **publicly visible** discussions outside of the network.

Comment: followup question, is this not permissible on *any* website? screenshots? really?!

Comment: @iight I had a few more related questions, but I found answers to most of them such as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo . The problem is that how much / how many can be used before it starts crossing the line of *fair use* as stated here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22123/200868.

Comment: This is not an official answer from Stack Overflow. I am not a lawyer.

However, it's my understanding that the fair use exemption is exactly for this use case.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Thanks.