# Can we make a free app on Earth Sciences Exchange with information from posts?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, licensing, collaboration

We are receiving a lot of questions at Earth Sciences Exchange asking for identification of stones.
I am trying to start a [list of the identified minerals we have](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/es-stack-exchanges-mineral-guide) on our site's Meta.

As list point to identified minerals, I have started to fill [a little sheet](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/15315/12525) with some information about the piece and the best poster's picture.

---

My ask is if we could make a free app – without any ads or commercial purpose – for students, share it on GitHub with the information of the posts, using get petitions to generate a kind of mineral guide? It would contain the poster's question and pictures, the top answer and the sheet, that may be edited in wiki mode.

Should we write the site asking for permission? It would be nice if we could use Stack Exchange's and Earth Science's logos.

Comment: You can make an app that uses the content from the sites as long as you follow the [attribution](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) rules stated in the [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/legal) bits. I'm pretty sure you [can't use their logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo), even if you ask. Create your own derivative work

Comment: Thanks @rene. I wanted to mix the logo with my own svg. Ok understood. I think all would be ok -and would look kindly official wich is nice- saying at the splash activity or so "Application performed at Earth Sciences Exchange". I guess I can't use a webviewer to load the posts, but I want just to download the info to a local database and have an "upgrade database" option -so the app would work with not connection for students at the field.

Comment: I'm fine with the app, I do object to your adding partially duplicate answers to ID questions promoting this. It feels like 'hijacking' this site for your own project.

Comment: Looking "kind of official" is exactly what is not permitted.  You need to be clear that you are using information from the SE site, but that your application is not under the control of SE.  Anything that would suggest SE has responsibility for your bugs / policies / whatever is quite improper.  That's the difference between "official" and not.

Comment: @Voigt the archi of the app is gonna be shared at github at public domain and if published with no adds. But the content is cc content from stack and authors. I just wanted to mean with my bad english is as the app should leave clear the content comes from stack's api it would have some kind of official perspective.

Comment: Thank you very much for the bounty. I'm glad my effort is appreciated, and hope to return the favor some day.

Comment: @Glorfindel You are welcome. I couldn't reach my programming level so quick without stackoverflow so it is me who is glad to return the favour

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed, and even [*encouraged*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/):

> All the content contributed to Stack Overflow or other Stack Exchange sites is [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (aka [cc-by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) licensed, **intended to be shared and remixed.**

<sub>(I added some emphasis)</sub>

However, pay close attention to the attribution rules:

> 1. **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network** in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. **Hyperlink directly to the original question** on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. **Show the author names** for every question and answer
> 4. **Hyperlink each author name** directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

That those hyperlinks won't work when your app is in offline mode is understandable and won't form a problem. There just needs to be an easy way to get there if your user does have an Internet connection.

Like @rene said in the comments, [you can't use the Stack Exchange logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo?noredirect=1&lq=1) for your app.